# Desktop-first trying to use media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello I developed this website desktop first and now I am trying to add a media query for mobile users. On the desktop my gallery is a flex grid, but I am trying to make it a single column so the picture are bigger on the mobile device. I appreciate the help

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
  
  body {
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:400;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#595959;
  }
  
  .header {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px 35px;
  }
  
  a {
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  }
  
  .menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  }
  
  .menu ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:24px;
  margin:15px;
  }
  
  .menu ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:24px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  }
  
  .menu ul li a:hover {
  color:red;
  }
  
  .sub-menu {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  background-color:#202020;
  }
  
  .menu li:hover a+.sub-menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  .name {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  width:320px;
  border:1px solid #FFF;
  }
  
  .name h5 {
  color:red;
  font-size:33px;
  text-align:left;
  }
  
  .name h1 {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:120px;
  line-height:100px;
  }
  
  .title {
  color:#000;
  font-size:24px;
  background-color:#595959;
  }
  
  .foot {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:right;
  font-size:10px;
  }
  
  .works {
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
  left:500px;
  }
  
  .preview {
  width:60%;
  }
  
  .preview2 {
  width:75%;
  }
  
  .preview3 {
  width:70%;
  }
  
  .page-title {
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top:90px;
  font-size:24px;
  }
  
  .gallery {
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  top:25%;
  color:#FFF;
  max-width:100%;
  }
  
  .gallery .image {
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
  margin:2%;
  }
  
  .image img {
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  }
  
  h6 {
  font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:left;
  }
  
  .artist-statement {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  font-size:16px;
  }
  
  .selfie {
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  left:780px;
  }

  @media screen (max-width: 480px) {
    body{
      width: 400px;
      font-size: 110%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .menu {
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  .gallery{
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>John Blair Graphic Designer :: Digital</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="drop" style="text-decoration:none" href="works.html">Works</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="digital.html">Digital</a></li>
                <li><a href="physical.html">Physical</a></li>
                <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="Home">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page-title">
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <h3>illustration</h3>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/Shelbs-01.png">
                        <img alt="illustration of beautiful woman" src="images/illustration/Shelbs-01.png"></a>
          <h6>My Queen</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/cheetahsketch.jpg">
                        <img alt="illustration of cheetah" src="images/illustration/cheetahsketch.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Cheetah Sketch</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/hardensketch.png">
                        <img alt="illustration of james harden" src="images/illustration/hardensketch.png"></a>
          <h6>Fear The Beard</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/lebronsketch.jpg">
                        <img alt="illustration of lebron james" src="images/illustration/lebronsketch.jpg"></a>
          <h6>TACO TUUUEESDAY</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/pigsketch.png">
                        <img alt="illustration of pig" src="images/illustration/pigsketch.png"></a>
          <h6>1-800-CASH-PIG</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/sludgesketch.jpg">
                        <img alt="illustration of sludge monster" src="images/illustration/sludgesketch.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Sludge Monster</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <h3 class="design">Design</h3>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/illustration/spain.jpg">
                        <img alt="illustration travel poster of spain" src="images/illustration/spain.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Spain Travel Poster</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/desgin/oldspice.jpg">
                        <img alt="old-spice-advertisement" src="images/desgin/oldspice.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Old Spice Advertisement</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/desgin/burger.jpg">
                    <img alt="blair's burgers Advertisement" src="images/desgin/burger.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Blair's Burgers</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/desgin/book.jpg">
                        <img alt="book sleeve" src="images/desgin/book.jpg"></a>
          <h6>Disoriented Book Cover</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <a target="_blank" href="images/desgin/BlairNewEventPoster-2.jpg">
                            <img alt="Ostrich festival poster" src="images/desgin/BlairNewEventPoster-2.jpg"></a>
          <h6>2018 Ostrich Festival</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/JBeezy3/pen/yLyNZdG

Answer (score 0):

The higher level selector is applied to those in your desktop css, use the same in a query:

```
.gallery .image {
    width: 100%;
}
```